How to kill a process from inside Cocoa Application?
I am trying to open PDF in Preview using NSWorkSpace. It opens my pdf in preview but when it doesn't terminate or close that preview when I click on close button.
Note: It does close the app when I remove App Sandbox, but I want to keep App Sandbox
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pdfApp: NSRunningApplication?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Open PDF") {
                if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Merged", withExtension: "pdf") {
                    openApp(at: pdfURL)
                }
            }
            
            Button("Close PDF") {
                closeApp()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    func openApp(at url: URL) {
        let success = NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
        
        if success {
            let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
            if let previewApp = runningApps.first(where: { $0.bundleIdentifier == "com.Apple.Preview" }) {
                pdfApp = previewApp
            }
        }
    }
    
    func closeApp() {
        // method - 1
        pdfApp?.terminate()
        
        // method - 2
        let pid = pdfApp?.processIdentifier
        if let pID = pid {
            kill(pID, SIGKILL)
        }
    }
    
}


I want to keep App Sandbox and able to close the opened app.

This is not possible. How about using a PDFView to show your PDF?

Try Process with a bundled script.
